# Creating 7zip SFX installer

Tags: windows-10, 7-zip, self-extracting

I'm trying to create self extracting archive with gui, I'm using 7-Zip 9.20 on Windows 10, I just want the files in the 7z file to extract to the `InstallPath` directory, without running the file. I created `aa.7z` file and put `aa.exe` in it, then used this command `copy /b 7zS.sfx + config.txt + aa.7z installer.exe`

with this config.txt

```
;!@Install@!UTF-8!
InstallPath="%PROGRAMFILES%\\aa"
Title="Installation"
BeginPrompt="aa"
ExtractDialogText="bb"
ExtractPathText="cc"
ExtractTitle="dd"
GUIFlags="8+32+64+256+4096"
GUIMode="1"
OverwriteMode="0"
Shortcut="Du,{%%T\\aa.exe},{},{},{as},{fs},{},{%%T\\aa.exe},{0}"
FinishMessage="finish"
;!@InstallEnd@!
```

When executing installer.exe, `ExtractDialogText`,`ExtractPathText`,`ExtractTitle` does not show up I only see `Title` and `BeginPrompt` Labels and two buttons Yes and No, When I click Yes I get the error `Can not find setup.exe`, I didn't want to run any file and I don't know what setup.exe is, also the file doesn't get extracted to InstallPath

Comment: The [official documentation](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/sfx.htm) doesn't have any of your non-working switches. Where did you read about them?

Comment: You really should not be putting stuff in `Program Files` if you are not actually running a windows installer.